# What is the equivalent of ALAssetsGroupPropertyPersistentID for Photos Framework

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios8, alassetslibrary, ios9, photokit

Since `ALAssetsGroup` was replaced by `PHAssetCollection` on Photos Framework how can I uniquely identify an asset collection (album) even if the user renames it? I was using `ALAssetsGroupPropertyPersistentID` before PhotoKit existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every PHCollection is a subclass of PHObject which has a property ***localIdentifier*** which never changes for a collection.